# Refresh screen after user interaction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, sleep

I am programming a application in xcode, for iOs. I have a code like this:

```
- (void)buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender{

    UIView *figure = (UIView *) [figures objectAtIndex:sender.tag];

    [figure.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
    [figure.layer setBorderColor: [UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
    sleep(1);
    [self cleanScreen];

}

- (void) cleanScreen {

    //Some code to hide all view objects

}
```

I hope that changes the border color and width are reflected on the screen for 1 second before the items are deleted by cleanScreen function. But it happens that these changes are not reflected and spent one second elements are deleted.

I want refresh screen before cleanScreen is called.

How to get the effect I want?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of:

```
sleep(1);
```

use:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(cleanScreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
```

with `sleep()` you are freezing the whole application

Comment: Nice solution! But how I can do the same if my funcition have a parameter (interger, for exemple).    
[self performSelector:@selector(cleanScreen:1) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];  
don't work. Or for example if I want delay other viewcontroller called with:
[self.view addSubview:self.bMar.view];

Comment: if your function only have one parameter you can send it in the `withObject:` argument, instead of `nil` create a `NSNumber` with the value

Comment: the comment regarding the view I don't understand it